# SAS Enterprise Guide / SQL Performance

Tags: sql, sas

I'm looking for a little guidance on a SAS/SQL performance issue I'm having. In SAS Enterprise Guide, I've created a program that creates a table. This table has about 90k rows:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS (
  SELECT id, SUM(myField)
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY id
)
```

I have a much larger table with millions of rows. Each row has an id. I want to sum values on this table, using only id's present in the 'test' table. I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 AS(
  SELECT big.id, SUM(big.myOtherField)
  FROM big
  INNER JOIN test
    ON test.id = big.id
  GROUP BY big.id
)
```

The problem I'm having is that it takes forever to run the second query against the big table with millions of records. I thought the inner join on the subset of id's would help (and maybe it is) but I wanted to make sure I was doing everything I could to speed it up.

I don't have any way to get information on the indexing of the underlying database. I'm more interested in getting the opinion of someone who has more SQL and SAS experience than me.

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is here without a better definition of "millions of records" and "takes forever".  Assuming no indexes, you'd expect the db to sort the big table on id and do a hash join with your new table "test", which shouldn't take *that* long.

Comment: How long does the inner join take, without the group by?  IE, just `create table test2 as select big.id from big inner join test on test.id=big.id;`

Comment: Also, how are you connecting to this database, and what sort of database?  You say you're doing this in EG; is this EG connected to a SAS server, or EG using a local SAS install?  How close network-wise is the database server (on the same machine, in the same room, in the same building, across the ocean...)

Comment: Sorry for the vague information.  I'm not sure how many rows are in the big table.  There are 90k id's in the subset, and tens of millions at least in the overall pool.

The EG is connected to a SAS server.  I'm trying to run the inner join with no group-by now.  I did some date-filtering that did reduce the time and at least return some results.  Everything works except for the speed.  It may just be that the table is too big!

Comment: So there's no other DBMS involved (SQL/Oracle/etc.)?  Just SAS datasets?

Comment: I'm not sure.  They are on a SASApp server with a Teradata engine.  The connection=globaldatabase=dbc and sql_functions=allsqlgeneration=dbms

Comment: Hmm, then we're out of my league as I've zero experience with TeraData.  General SQL suggestions apply - try splitting the join and the group by, join into a table in memory then group by in a separate step - but beyond that I have no idea (other than 'it's just too much data to be fast').

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I agree, it seems like it might just be due to the size.  I put some more constraints and got it working.  I mostly wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something grossly incorrect in my inexperience with SAS.  I'm trying to learn more about it, my background is mostly R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you show in your question, you are joining two SAS data sets, not two database objects.  In any case, you can speed up the processing by defining indexes on the JOIN columns used in each table.  Assuming you have permission to do so, here are examples:

```
proc sql;
   create index id on big(id);
   create index id on test(id);
quit;
```

Of course, you probably should first check the table definition before doing that.  You can use the "describe" statement to see the structure:

```
proc sql;
   describe table big;
quit;
```

Indexes improve access performance at the cost of disk space and update maintenance.  Once created, the indexes will be a permanent part of the SAS data set and will be automatically updated if you use SQL INSERT or DELETE statements.  But be aware that the indexes will be deleted if you recreate the data set with a simple data step.

On the other hand, if these tables really are in an external database (like Oracle for example), you have a different challenge.  If that's the case, I'd ask a new question and provide a complete example of the SAS code you are using (including and libname statements).

Comment: I don't know that defining an index on a unique ID (which I assume `ID` is) will help you much... if the index has as many values as the original table, it's not much faster (perhaps not any faster, as SAS will load either into a hash table, unless the source table has a lot of columns which slows the load significantly).

Comment: Thanks Bob, this is all useful info.  I ended up getting it to work by adding some restrictions on the dataset to help narrow down the values.  Still, this is stuff I can definitely use.

Comment: Since you mention Teradata in another comment, there are many other performance suggestions that can be made.  You might want to ask another question and this time show the complete PROC SQL code you are using.  That will make it clear if you are joining to SAS datasets or to Teradata tables.  For best performance with Teradata, it is better to write native SQL using the "pass-thru" technique.  My answer about indexes was only for SAS datasets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with non-SAS data, ie, data that resides in a SQL DB or a no-SQL database for that matter, you will see significant improvements in performance using pass-through SQL or, if supported and you have the licenses for it, in-database processing.

One important point about proc sql vs pass-through sql.  Proc sql, by default, creates duplication of the original source data in SAS datasets prior to doing the work.  Whereas, pass-through just requests the result set from the source data provider.  In short, you can imagine that a table with 5 million rows will take a lot longer to use with proc sql (even if you are only interested in about 1% of the data) than if you just have to pull that 1% of data across the network using the pass-through mechanism.